# Has anyone had trouble with Intellisense in Visual Studio when using UltraVNC?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, vnc

a colleague and I are trying pair programming for the first time.  We both remote into a development machine; I'm using RemoteDesktop and my colleague is using UltraVNC.  This works great except that he can't see the Intellisense dropdown in Visual Studio 2008.  According to online posts, this may be something to do with DirectDraw, but I don't see much by way of a workaround.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: This is true also with TightVNC, the tooltips and exception boxes don't show up at all on VNC. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [this thread](http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?p=17240) at UltraVNC's site; you may just need to enable **capture alpha blending** on the UltraVNC server. (Unfortunately I haven't found a fix for TightVNC.)

Comment: Thanks JYelton, that did the trick!  Much appreciated.  Only problem now is it seems to have made the mouse movement really jerky.  Perhaps there is some parameter I can tweak to calm it down.

Comment: Good luck with it, I haven't had that issue exactly, nor can I reproduce it.